# Repeating String N times - multiplication VS enumerator

Tags: ruby, string, integer, enumeration

What is the difference between using a multiplication (assuming n is an integer):

```
new_string = string * n
```

and an enumerator:

```
new_string = ""
n.times do { new_string += string }`
```

The output seems the same, but I'm not sure about which method is *proper/correct* to do it.

I'd appreciate some input on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String#*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-2A) is implemented in C, but I expect a Ruby equivalent is the following.

```
class String
  def *(n)
    return "" if n.zero?
    (n-1).times.reduce(dup) { |s,_| s << self }
  end
end
```

```
str = 'abc'
str*(3)
  #=> "abcabcabc"
```

We see that, for `n > 0`, `str` is appended to the `dup` of `str` `n-1` times. No temporary arrays are created. This does not mutate `str` (`str #=> "abc"`).

Now consider:

```
str = 'abc'
n = 3

new_string = ""
n.times do { new_string += str }
```

Neither does this mutate `str`, but since `new_string += str` expands to

```
new_string = new_string + str
```

we see that the right side of this expression causes `n` arrays to be created, with the variable `new_string` assigned to each in turn. As a result, `n-1` temporary arrays are orphaned and must be garbage-collected. There is no problem doing that but it is a relatively inefficient operation.

Answer (score 0):

The output should differ. The first option creates a new instance of a `String` that contains `string` repeated `n` times. The second option mutates original `string` in every iteration, so as a result it's repeated much more than `n` times.

For instance:

```
string = 'Abc'
n = 3
n.times do { string += string }
```

values of `string` after subsequent iterations will be:

```
init: Abc
'AbcAbc'
'AbcAbcAbcAbc'
```

This may work in the same manner if you use a different string as a buffer:

```
new_string = ""
n.times { new_string += string }
```

I think that `string * n` is more memory efficient (only one new allocation).

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about initializing an empty string. Fixed the post.

Comment: If you initialize the empty string, the difference is mostly in memory footprint and readability. I strongly recommend `string * n` version